# Is there a diagram software that automatically converts circuit diagrams into physical wiring diagrams on breadboards?

Tags: circuit-design

Is there a diagram software that automatically converts logic circuit diagrams such as the following one (diagram_1)

[image]

into physical wiring diagrams on breadboards, such as the following one (diagram_2)?

[image]

I'm aware that diagram_1 and diagram_2 don't match each other. The following ones match each other though they are not diagrams generated by software.

[image]

[image]

I may not use the appropriate terms, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: GPT 4.5 perhaps?

Comment: Chances of human construction errors interpreting a *schematic diagram* are less than interpreting a *breadboard physical wiring diagram*. Schematic diagrams evolved as the best method of conveying connections between electrical elements - for humans doing eye-to-hand construction.

Comment: @glen_geek thanks for your reply, do schematic diagrams refer to diagram_1?

Comment: Yes - 1st photo I'd call a schematic, as is the last (hand-drawn) photo. In that 1st photo, all those vertical lines on the right side are difficult for an eye to follow but it is done for a reason...it is a bus-structure where all lines are functionally related. A *breadboard physical wiring diagram* loses all functional relationships.

Comment: @periblepsis:  I'd like to see the hash that a chatbot makes of that task.  It ought to be quite entertaining.

Comment: @JRE I hear they will replace all of us and that there will be no jobs left over, in a few years' time. ;) The chatbots lie all the time. But they lie well. They will probably make the wiring look right. It's just that when wiring it up, nothing will necessarily work. :) Of course, they might get lucky, too. ;) I expect everything here to be replaced by chatbots asking questions and chatbots providing answers.... soon enough.

Comment: diagram_1 is a `logic diagram` ... a schematic diagram would include pin numbers for all of the gates

Answer (score 1):

> *Does there exist diagram software that automatically converts circuit
> diagrams into physical wiring diagrams on breadboards?*

It's unlikely to exist for a few reasons: -

- The only people who would want it are beginner hobbyists hence, the market is limited
- If it did exist then the learning curve for beginner hobbyists (equivalent to learning how to use pro software like KiCAD) would be too much for them
- Beginner hobbyists almost certainly would expect it for free

Hence there is no viable market opportunity for such a piece of software.

But, let's assume that a piece of software does exist: once the beginner has used it once or twice, the magical curtain lifts, the light enters the room and the brain has then grasped how to do it (without using the software).

Then, they will never consider doing it that way again. In other words they have progressed on the path of learning. We do not play with our toys (should we still have them) that we received when we were babies do we? Well maybe some folk do.

So, there is no market and the answer to your question is logically a big no. That doesn't mean someone hasn't created one of course.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but Moritz Klein employs a fairly intuitive method of manually drawing a connection diagram on dot grid paper for transferring a wiring schematic to solderable protoboard in his video on designing an analog synth VCO, (see "Stripboard layout design" @ 6:19 and onwards).

As he points out, it's a bit labour-intensive, but it *can* net some great results.

https://youtu.be/OCAb2UoSPs0?feature=shared&t=379

And as a sidenote, most electronic CAD software comes bundled with or is integrable with PCB design software, but that kind of cuts out the breadboard middleman, which you might not find desirable if you're just prototyping. Admittedly, figuring out which CAD software you prefer is a whole other rabbit hole.

My best advice when breadboarding is to make connections/jumpers as short as is reasonable and manipulable without sacrificing visual clarity of what the circuit's doing. When in doubt, err on the side of understanding how it all connects, which might mean bigger breadboards and longer jumpers.